# HTML Anchor element & onload

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp for the anchor element and I am a bit confused because it does not go over all the CSS parts of it. I know there is a:active, but what is the rest, a full list?

I am needing this because for my second problem involves some of these anchor tags or whatever these are called. I am trying to have it so that after the website fully loads, it changes the CSS from

```
-webkit-opacity: 0.5;
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
```

to

```
-webkit-opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
```

I have attempted to do so by putting the body element in a class with the first CSS. I then put in the element `onload="then the second CSS here"`. This does not seem to do fade it from greyish to clear.

Here is exactly what I am trying to get: When you load the page it is slightly grayed out with the first CSS I posted, then after it is fully loaded transition it to clear. This will be happening to everything inside and the body element itself.

I am confused on how to do this.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2

Comment: `<body onload>` is an event handler, which is Javascript.

Comment: In the first part of your question I think you are referring to HTML anchor pseudo elements (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/) but I dont think those will help for what you want to do

Comment: Thank you for the first part of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simplified version of what you're trying to do with the `onload`.

A very long-loading image (5.5mb):

```
<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Mignon_Vanitas.png?343243dfdf4515' style='width: 500px; height: 500px;'/>
```

The `onload`:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.style.opacity = 1;
};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7r6osy7/1/

To make it transition, see @Gael's answer (hint: you use classes on a containing element, like adding `yourTransitionClassName` to the `document.body` element).

Note: Change the number after the `?` in the image url, e.g.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Mignon_Vanitas.png?**343243dfdf4515**

Change that to make the image re-load and trigger the `onload` handler again.

**EDIT:**

Using the transition in `opacity`:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .2;
}
body.transition {
    transition:  opacity 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.classList.add('transition');
};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7r6osy7/3/

Answer (score 1):

Visit mdn to have more informations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active#See_also

Then, to use a transition when the page is loaded:

```js
window.onload= function(){
  document.querySelector("#loadStage").classList.add("loaded");
}


i=0;
while( i++ < 1000000 ); //emulate page load
```

```css
#loadStage{
  background:#aaa;
  transition:  background-color 1s;
  
  width:300px;height:300px
}

#loadStage.loaded{
  background: green; 
}
```

```html
<div id="loadStage" class="initial"></div>
```

Comment: This would work, except that I am using this on the body which has multiple divider elements in it... Not so much want the background to be green. I want this to apply for everything inside of the body element. What else could I change green to if I would want this to be everything inside of the body element.

Comment: I used the background property to make a visible exampe. Just replace it by `opacity`, or other animatable property.